# Alternative to 100vh for fixed positioned element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div (top navigation)` that is nested inside a `flex` container. When the `top-nav` expands, I want it to occupy the full height of the viewport. I know this can be achieved by setting a height of `100vh` but it is not widely supported. So, I need a more traditional way to achieve this.

The `html` and `body` have a `height 100%` but the content of the view overflows and I can scroll the page.

What I have right now is:

```
.top-nav .top-nav-links-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;        
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this (apart from setting height to `100vh`)?

Comment: If your element is a direct child of the body, I think your code should work fine. But I believe `vh`, and `vw` are pretty widely supported.

Comment: No the element isn't a direct child of body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Viewport units like `vh` and `vw` are [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport); Use them.

The other alternative is to set the position to `fixed` and set `bottom: 0`.  `height` assumes the height of the parent element and doesn't take position, margin or padding into account; `bottom` assumes an offset from the bottom of the parent container. Same goes for `width` vs `right`. Remember, you should not use `height` and `bottom` at the same time or they'll override each other.

Here is a working example.

```css
.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">this will be fullscreen with a top offset</div>

<div class="body">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed arcu quis dui congue pulvinar. Ut scelerisque suscipit ipsum, in elementum velit aliquet sit amet. Nulla tempus iaculis vestibulum. Mauris eu odio id dui consectetur blandit facilisis nec metus. Nullam laoreet risus et aliquam viverra. Sed eu imperdiet metus. Vivamus at dui turpis.</p>
</div>
```

Regardless of which units you use, the page is always going to be able to scroll behind the expanded nav. This shouldn't be a problem if your navbar is also given a fixed position so it can follow along.

Comment: setting bottom 0 does the same thing as 100%. Have tried that already.

Comment: @HimanshuArora you must make sure to *remove* the height if you're going to set `bottom`. I've updated with a working example.

Comment: yes I did remove the height 100%. I have content overflowing the body (and thus page scrolls), does setting bottom to 0 work for you in that scenario as well? It didn't work for me.

Comment: I've updated with an example of the body being longer and the fixed position still holding on.

Comment: Regardless of which units you use, the page is always going to be able to scroll behind the expanded nav.

Comment: somehow now it works for me too. both bottom 0 and the height 100% is now working. earlier it was taking the height of the content (couldn't figure out why). Now the problem is I don't know what I changed accidentaly in the view that it works .. lol

Comment: @HimanshuArora use your version control software to do a diff and compare what changed.

Answer (score 7):

Strongly recommend against using `vw`/`vh` in web pages. They are very poorly supported by Safari, especially with the notch for iPhoneX*.

The other answer provided a solid alternative, using `position`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

will take up 100% of the first ancestor with a position other than the default, `static`.

using `position: fixed` will make it take up the whole layout viewport.

When you have the notch on iPhoneX, 100vw includes the notch in its measurement for iOS Safari even when your DOM does not include it.

100vh is not what you expect it to be on iOS Safari (it's a bit more than 100 viewport height).

`window.innerHeight/Width` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width` are another consistency nightmare in Safari, but that's a topic for another day.

I work on one of those billion user website, and had to banned my team from using `vw`/`vh` in our code for this reason.